# Wildcard certificate problem

Tags: iis-7, certificate, wildcard

My client bought wildcard certificate for domain `example.com`. We have setup ssl on website which is used under `something.more.example.com` and the wildcard certificate is reporting problems. Is there a way to workaround this other then changing `something.more.example.com` to `somethingmore.example.com` ? I always thought I can have as many subdomains of subdomains as I want with wildcard certificate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think as it is *.example.com it is only valid for immediate sub-domains, it does not support nesting. You'll have to name it somethingmore.example.com, or buy either an explicit something.more.example.com certificate or another wildcard as *.more.example.com.

Answer (score 1):

Wildcard certificates secure all of the subdomains **at the level you specify when you submit your request**:

```
A Wildcard SSL certificate secures your website URL, and an unlimited number of its subdomains. A single Wildcard certificate can secure both www.coolexample.com, and blog.coolexample.com.

Wildcard certificates secure all of the subdomains at the level you specify when you submit your request. Just add an asterisk (*) in the subdomain area of the common name where you want to specify the wildcard. For example:

If you configure *.coolexample.com, you can secure
www.coolexample.com
photos.coolexample.com
blog.coolexample.com, etc.

If you configure *.www.coolexample.com, you can secure
mail.www.coolexample.com
photos.www.coolexample.com
blog.www.coolexample.com, etc.
```

From [GoDaddy Help Center](http://help.godaddy.com/article/567)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the *.more.example.com as a sub alt name to the wildcard or ucc/san. I know ssl.com certs can do it