# What type of errors will users encounter for subdomains that are not accepted by a wildcard certificate?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

This is just a follow up clarification question to the one over [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/315517/wildcard-certificate-problem).

I plan to buy the following wild card certificate for my domain:

*.example.com (sample only)

but I want to secure the following urls:

*.tabs.apps.example.com
*.apps.example.com

Given my wildcard certificate, will users accessing my site encounter problems like untrusted certificate etc? If yes what kind of errors/problems will our site's visitors encounter aside from untrusted certificate if any?

Answer (score 0):

The point of a wildcard certificate (as I understand it) is that it applies to all subdomains off your domain. So users won't get any errors with your given examples.